# Cannot save data to database Python

Tags: python, mysql

I have a table called `category`

```
TABLES["category"] = ("""
    CREATE TABLE category (
        category_id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        category_name VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (category_id)
    )
""")
```

when I ran `INSERT INTO category (category_name) VALUES ('test')` using `mysql-connector-python`, the value is not saved. But when I did this in my database directly, this was stored.

THank you in advance.

**EDIT**

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user="root", database="my_db")
cursor = cnx.cursor()
```

Comment: How do you connect to the DB? Does any other query work from python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If other queries work from Python, maybe adding commit after your insertion solves the problem.
something like this:

```
INSERT INTO category (category_name) 
VALUES ('test')
COMMIT;
```