# Not saving data mysql-connector-python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I'm trying to save data inside MySQL from python script.
I have imported `mysql-connector-python`, and I tried to save some data using it, like this:

```
import mysql.connector

connection = mysql.connector.connect(user="root",database="test_db")
cursor = cnx.connection()

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO category (category_name) VALUES ('test')")
print(cursor.fetchall())
```

But I got nothing printed out except `[]`. I checked if the data was successfully saved t o the database, but nothing was saved. So I tried `INSERT INTO category (category_name) VALUES ('test')` directly inside my database, and it worked.
There's one thing caught my sight is that after I ran `INSERT INTO category (category_name) VALUES ('test')` my database and successfully created the data, the data's primary key was set to `2`. The database is newly created one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot save data to database Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69065319/cannot-save-data-to-database-python)

Answer (score 1):

Under cursor.execute()
Add

```
 connection.commit()
```

Then in your sql server, retrieve the data using:

```
  USE databaseName
  SELECT * FROM tableName
```

Comment: commit for the win. 100%

Answer (score 0):

An `INSERT` query will not return anything for a `.fetchall()`.

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO category (category_name) VALUES ('test')")
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM category")
print(cursor.fetchall())
```

might work better...

Comment: I have already checked that data is not saved.